Proof of Second Welfare Theorem with infinitely many goods
I'm trying to understand the proof of the Second Welfare Theorem and I'm still struggling with the intuition behind the use of a linear functional as a mathematical instrument in order to prove that the initial pareto optimal allocation comes from a competitive equilibrium. I've read the proof in this lecture proof and I'd like to be sure if the Riesz representation is only an advantage for the aesthetics of the proof or something necessary if we want to obtain the result in a particular manner. I've also read the proof present in the IMEG by Acemoglu but it seems kind of more involved than the proof of the lecture linked. It is somehow different?
